# Using vectors to show that if the diagonals of a parallelogram have the same length, then show that the parallelogram is a rectangle.

Tags: geometry, vectors

Prove this statement by using vectors:

> If the diagonals of a parallelogram have the same length, then show that the parallelogram is a rectangle.

I’ve tried using $\|x\|^2 = x \cdot x$, where $\cdot$ is dot product, to show that the opposite sides are of equal length, but this just shows that the sides are facing the opposite direction, even though I set the sides facing the same direction.

So I set the two diagonals as x⃗ and y ⃗. $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{c}$ are the opposite sides, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{d}$ are the other opposite sides.

x⃗ = - $\vec{a}$ + $\vec{d}$ = $\vec{b}$ - $\vec{c}$

y = $\vec{d}$ + $\vec{c}$ = $\vec{a}$ + $\vec{b}$

The length of the diagonals are the same. There are several ways I did this and this is one of them.

$\|\vec{x}\| = \|\vec{y}\|$

$\|\vec{x}\|^2 = \|\vec{y}\|^2$

$ \vec{x}\cdot \vec{x} = \vec{y}\cdot \vec{y}$

($-\vec{a} + \vec{d}) \cdot (\vec{b} - \vec{c}$) = ($\vec{d} + \vec{c}) \cdot (\vec{a} + \vec{b}$)

$-\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} + \vec{a} \cdot \vec{c} + \vec{d} \cdot \vec{b} - \vec{d} \cdot \vec{c} = \vec{d} \cdot \vec{a} + \vec{d} \cdot \vec{b} + \vec{a} \cdot \vec{c} + \vec{c} \cdot \vec{b}$

$-\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} - \vec{d} \cdot \vec{c} = \vec{d} \cdot \vec{a} + \vec{c} \cdot \vec{b}$

$ 
-\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} - \vec{d} \cdot \vec{a} = \vec{c} \cdot \vec{b} + \vec{d} \cdot \vec{c}
$

We can collect terms because dot product is commutative.

$
-\vec{a} \cdot ( \vec{d} + \vec{b}) = \vec{c} ( \vec{d} + \vec{b})
$

We can assume that $- \vec{a} = \vec{c}$. This is the part where I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. I set the direction of $ \vec{a}$ and $\vec{c}$ facing the same way, but now they are facing in opposite direction.

Comment: When is a parallellogram a rectangle? It has to do with angles, so you should have a look at a formula for angles between vectors, and try to see how to use information about the diagonals there.

Comment: I’ve tried doing that to and I got negative length for opposite sides, which doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @henrysilver Add that attempt. Maybe we'll spot the mistake

Comment: HINT. If $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are two consecutive sides of the parallelogram, what are the vectors corresponding to its diagonals?

Comment: HINT: Which number is the same as its opposite?

Answer (score 2):

If we have a parallelogram with a vertex at $\vec{p}_0$, and sides $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ starting at that vertex, the other three vertices are
$$\begin{aligned}
\vec{p}_1 &= \vec{p}_0 + \vec{u} \\
\vec{p}_2 &= \vec{p}_0 + \vec{v} \\
\vec{p}_3 &= \vec{p}_0 + \vec{u} + \vec{v} \\
\end{aligned}$$
and the diagonals $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ are
$$\begin{aligned}
\vec{x} = \vec{p}_3 - \vec{p}_0 &= \vec{v} + \vec{u} \\
\vec{y} = \vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_1 &= \vec{v} - \vec{u} \\
\end{aligned}$$
and their lengths are
$$\begin{aligned}
\left\lVert\vec{x}\right\rVert &= \left\lVert \vec{v} + \vec{u} \right\rVert \\
\left\lVert\vec{y}\right\rVert &= \left\lVert \vec{v} - \vec{u} \right\rVert \\
\end{aligned}$$
noting that if $\lVert\vec{v}\rVert = 0$ or $\lVert\vec{u}\rVert = 0$, the parallelogram is degenerate (has zero area, is a line or a point).  In what case is $\lVert\vec{x}\rVert = \lVert\vec{y}\rVert$?

Can you take it from here?